# Delay variable computation within another string variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write an Oracle Procedure that contains a few blocks of SQL code. And in-between the blocks I want to insert into `LOG_TBL` an incremented step number and `SYSTIMESTAMP`.
But what actually happens is that `V_STEP_NUM` is computed only one time, that is when I assign a value to `V_INSERT_LOG_SQL`. Thus I get just a bunch of rows with `STEP_NUMBER` of `0`.

However, if I replace `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_INSERT_LOG_SQL;` with the explicit SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'INSERT INTO LOG_TBL (STEP_NUMBER,BEGIN_TIME) VALUES 
    ('||V_STEP_NUM||',SYSTIMESTAMP)'
```

then it works as expected, with incremented step numbers.

What have I gotten wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure
IS
    V_STEP_NUM NUMBER(2);
    V_INSERT_LOG_SQL CLOB;

BEGIN
    V_STEP_NUM := 0;

    V_INSERT_LOG_SQL := 'INSERT INTO LOG_TBL (STEP_NUMBER,BEGIN_TIME) VALUES ('||V_STEP_NUM||',SYSTIMESTAMP)';

    BEGIN
        V_STEP_NUM:= V_STEP_NUM + 1;
    END;    

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_INSERT_LOG_SQL;
    COMMIT;

    [SOME MORE SQL CODE]

    BEGIN
        V_STEP_NUM:= V_STEP_NUM + 1;
    END;    

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_INSERT_LOG_SQL;
        COMMIT;
    END; 

    [SOME MORE SQL CODE]
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `V_INSERT_LOG_SQL` at the start as

```
insert into log_tbl (step_number,begin_time) values (0,SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

and then never change it. To pass a new value each time, either construct a new string each time to capture the current value of `V_INSERT_LOG_SQL`, or (better for your SQL cache), pass it as a bind variable:

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure
as
    v_step_num number(2) := 0;
    v_insert_log_sql clob := 'insert into log_tbl (step_number,begin_time) values (:b1,SYSTIMESTAMP)';
begin    
    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;
    execute immediate v_insert_log_sql using v_step_num;

    --[some more code]

    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;

    execute immediate v_insert_log_sql using v_step_num;
    commit;
end;
```

However, unless there is more to the requirement than you are showing here, you don't need dynamic SQL at all:

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure
as
    v_step_num number(2) := 0;
begin
    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;
    insert into log_tbl (step_number,begin_time) values (v_step_num,SYSTIMESTAMP);

    --[some more code]

    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;

    insert into log_tbl (step_number,begin_time) values (v_step_num,SYSTIMESTAMP);
    commit;
end;
```

or better still, use a separate procedure for logging:

```
create or replace procedure log_message
    ( p_step_num    in log_tbl.step_number%type
    , p_begin_time  in log_tbl.begin_time%type default systimestamp )
as
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    insert into log_tbl
    ( step_number, begin_time )
    values
    ( p_step_num, p_begin_time );

    commit;
end log_message;
```

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure
as
    v_step_num number(2) := 0;
begin    
    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;

    log_message(v_step_num);

    --[some more code]

    v_step_num := v_step_num + 1;

    log_message(v_step_num);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to write a detailed answer. Bind variables for some reason didn't seem to work. 
I ended up using a separate procedure for logging, similar to what you proposed. And it works well.